# Female vocal motivating songs

Tags: electronic-music, house, dj

I want to find more music for jogging / swimming. I like motivating Progressive house / light dubstep music with female vocals. Hope you guys could help me out with some channels / musicians with that specific music type.

I'm searching for songs similar to those:

BRKLYN ft. Lenachka - Steal Your Heart (Breathe Carolina Remix)

DVBBS & Shaun Frank - LA LA LAND ft. Delaney Jane

3LAU - How You Love Me ft. Bright Lights

Lana Del Rey vs Cedric Gervais 'Summertime Sadness' Remix

The Chainsmokers ft ROZES Roses ZAXX Remix

Thanks for helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tritonal - Blackout

4 Strings - Take Me Away ( Dave Darell Remix)

tyDi ft. Melanie Fontana-Redefined

John Dahlbäck feat. Rebecca & Fiona - Honors

Matteo Marini & Ellie Lawson Butterfly Heart

CLMD feat. Sirena - Wild Men

John Dahlbäck ft. Melanie Fontana - Fireflies

Anna of the North - Sway (The Chainsmokers Remix)

Alison Wonderland - Run

Execute & Cristian Marchi feat. Christine P LG - In Love With A Stranger

Favright - Taking Over (feat. Cassandra Kay)

Haywyre - Time (feat. CoMa)

BYNON & Bishøp - Hey Hey

Alesso Ft. Sirena - Sweet Escape (Pep & Rash Remix)

Thinking About You (EDX's Belo Horizonte At Night Remix)

Roger Shah, JES & Brian Laruso - Higher Than the Sun

Tritonal ft. Skyler Stonestreet - Electric Glow

Krewella - Alive (Cash Cash x Kalkutta Remix)

Kaskade - Never Sleep Alone

Steve Aoki & Moxie - I Love It When You Cry

Eva Simons - I Don't Like You

Sander van Doorn & Adrian Lux ft. Inpetto - No More Serious Eagles (Jacob van Hage Mashup)

The Knocks feat. Sneaky Sound System - The One (Dave Edwards Remix)

Singularity - Horizon

Singularity - Rift

Thomas Newson feat. Angelika Vee - Don't Hold Us

Borgeous & Shaun Frank feat. Delaney Jane - This Could Be Love

Magnetie - Girl

PeaceTreaty - In Time (Singularity Remix)

Chris Lake feat. Jareth - Helium

Cash Cash - Surrender

Disclosure - You & Me (Flume Remix)

Tiësto ft. Kyler England - Take Me

Seven Lions - Don't Leave

Sander van Doorn, Martin Garrix, DVBBS - Gold Skies

Bassnectar - You & Me

M-3ox ft. Heidrun - Beating Of My Heart (Matisse & Sadko Radio Remix)

Borgeous - Invincible

Ellie Goulding - Anything Could Happen (Flinch Remix)

Zedd - Find You

Manufactured Superstars featuring Danni Rouge - Like Satellites

Tritonal feat. Phoebe Ryan - Now Or Never

Tritonal - Still With Me (Ft. Cristina Soto) (Seven Lions Remix)

Seven Lions with Myon and Shane 54 - Strangers (Feat. Tove Lo)

Krewella - Live For The Night

Hardwell & Dyro feat. Bright Lights - Never Say Goodbye

3LAU, Paris & Simo feat. Bright Lights - Escape

Cazzette - Beam Me Up

Hurricane- Dzeko & Torres (Feat. Sarah Mcleod)

Blackmill Feat. Veela - Let It Be

Nadia Ali, Starkillers & Alex Kenji - Pressure (Alesso Remix)

Well, I went through my list of songs and this is what I came up with. I hope you enjoy them as much as I did.

Comment: You'll never know how thankful I am to you!! I love almost all of those songs, and it takes me forever to find this amount of songs on my own! Thanks!!!!!!